# Concatenating multiple lines of a text file together in perl

Tags: perl

I'm working with some sizable data files - 90012 lines each.  Each file contains weather data from 7,501 weather stations for each day of the year.  There are 12 lines for each weather station, one for each month.  A sample of the data is below (truncated to show only three days for each month).

I would like to write a perl script that concatenates all 12 lines for each weather station onto a single line for easier post processing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
AQW00061705 01      824C   824C   824C
AQW00061705 02      826C   826C   826C
AQW00061705 03      829C   829C   829C
AQW00061705 04      826C   826C   826C
AQW00061705 05      821C   821C   821C
AQW00061705 06      813C   813C   813C
AQW00061705 07      806C   805C   805C
AQW00061705 08      801C   801C   801C
AQW00061705 09      807C   807C   808C
AQW00061705 10      812C   812C   812C
AQW00061705 11      816C   816C   817C
AQW00061705 12      823C   823C   823C
CAW00064757 01      204Q   202Q   200Q
```

Comment: So your desired output has 365/366 columns (plus one col for the wheather station's ID)?

Comment: Correct!  Station ID followed by a data point for each day of the year (there's only 365 in this file).

Comment: Please, provide sampel output

Comment: Can we assume that the month numbers/lines are always increasing? Always from 01 to 12 and not 01, 03, 04, 02, ...?

Comment: Yes ... Month numbers are always increasing.

Comment: Desired Output:  AQW00061705  824C   824C   824C  826C   826C   826C ...

Comment: Although I gave an answer below – please note that **SO is _not_ a code writing service** and it would have been much better if you'd shown a) some effort (i.e. _your code_) and b) where you got problems.

Comment: PerlDuck ... I appreciate the comments.  I'm new to the site and should have shown at least one of my many failed attempts.  My apologies!

Comment: No problem. We all started once. Perhaps you may want to refer to [ask] and provide a [mcve] next time.

Comment: What, no puppy? How would you like your solution wrapped, sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %station;
while(my $line = <>) {
    my ($id, undef, @day_data) = split(' ', $line);
    push @{$station{$id}}, @day_data;
}

foreach my $sid (sort keys %station) {
    print $sid, ' ', join(' ', @{ $station{$sid} }), "\n";
}
```

And then

```
./script.pl your_wheather_file
```

gives the following output:

```
AQW00061705 824C 824C 824C 826C 826C 826C 829C 829C 829C 826C 826C 826C 821C 821C 821C 813C 813C 813C 806C 805C 805C 801C 801C 801C 807C 807C 808C 812C 812C 812C 816C 816C 817C 823C 823C 823C
CAW00064757 204Q 202Q 200Q
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ape 'chomp if $. % 12; $G && s/^$G//; $G=$F[0]' file
```

Deletes newlines except for every 12th newline. Deletes the first field if it is the same as the first field on the previous line.

---

Earlier suggestion:

```
perl -pe 'chomp if $. % 12' file
```

Comment: Good catch guy ^^ +1

Comment: But I think we are wrong : must be grouped by weather station that is not defined by OP

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (one-liner) :

```
perl -lne '
    $. % 12 == 0 and print "";
    printf("%s ", $_);
' file
```

As far as it use default line by line mode, it should not be a problem to process a BIG file with this and redirect the output to a new file.

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk 'NR%12==0{print ""} {printf("%s ", $0)}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!